# Threads calling the same code resulting in deadlock [Mysql]

Tags: mysql, node.js, multithreading, deadlock

**Background:**

I have a stock market website, therefore consistency is extremely important to me. To accommodate this, I tend to utilize the most strict isolation level SERIALIZABLE.

Initial testing worked fine, but stress testing my back-end code with threads has revealed a nasty dead-lock.

**Problem**:

Ive isolated the problem to the api endpoint /open. This endpoint calls many functions that need to execute under a transaction. I will put the code below but here is a high-level of what locks are being acquired

- getBuyingPower - Lock User ROW and get their buying power
- await Users.update - Update User ROW with decreased buying power
- createLedgerEntry - Inserts entry into LEDGER table
- createStockOwner - Inserts entry into StockOwners table AND updates  payout and pot size columns for universe TABLE

***createStockOwner*** As little as it seems that I understand how locks work, I have to guess this is where the issue is.
As this function updates the payout and pot size for a given universe

This table looks like
universeId, universeName, potSize, payout

All the threads are different users, but they are all in the same universe, meaning every thread is trying to update the SAME row.

Now my belief was that since I acquire the locks in the same order on every thread (there are running the same code), that the serializable lock would simply wait for the one before it to finish before updating the row. I dont know why they would wait on each other.

**What Ive tried:**

I implemented a retry middleware, in which if a transaction fails due to deadlock to retry a max of 3 times. This did not solve the problem.

I know that debugging deadlocks can be tough, so I dont expect an answer to be given here, but please send me tips on how to debug this, and correct me where I am wrong about how the Serializable lock works.

**Code:**

```
router.post('/open', async (req, res) => {
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction({ isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE });
try {
    const { token, universeId } = req.body;
    const userId = extractUserFromToken(token);
    const buyingPower = await getBuyingPower(userId, transaction);

    if (buyingPower < 1) {
        throw new Error('Not enough buying power');
    }

    await Users.update({ balance: buyingPower - 1 }, { where: { id: userId }, transaction: transaction });
    const ledgerEntry = await createLedgerEntry({
        userId,
        type: 'purchase',
        amount: 1,
    }, transaction)
    const universe = await getUniverse([universeId]);
    if (universe.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Universe does not exist');
    }

    const stocks = await getAllStockCountInUniverse(universeId);
    const randomStock = await chooseRandomStock(stocks);
    const stock = await getStockById(randomStock.stockId)

    await createStockOwner({
        ledgerid: ledgerEntry.id,
        stockuuid: uuidv4(),
        stockId: stock.id,
        currentOwner: userId,
        universeId: universeId,
    }, transaction)

    await transaction.commit();

    res.json({ stock });
} catch (error) {
    await transaction.rollback();
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
}
});
```

ERROR:

```
Unable to update pot size: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Code in Question:

```
const createStockOwner = async (stockOwnerData, transaction) => {
try {
    const stockOwner = await StockOwners.create(stockOwnerData, { transaction });
    await updatePotSize(stockOwnerData.universeId, transaction)
    await updatePayout(stockOwnerData.universeId, 1, transaction);
    return stockOwner;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error('Could not create stock owner');
}
};


const updatePotSize = async (universeId, transaction) => {
try {
    const universe = await Universes.findOne({
        where: {
            id: universeId
        }, transaction
    });
    const potSize = universe.potSize;
    await universe.update({
        potSize: potSize + 1
    }, { transaction });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to update pot size:', error.message);
}
}

  const updatePayout = async (universeId, amount, transaction) => {
try {
    if (isNaN(amount) || amount === null) {
        throw new Error('Invalid amount value');
    }

    const universe = await Universes.findOne({
        where: {
            id: universeId
        }, transaction
    });

    if (!universe) {
        throw new Error('Universe not found');
    }
    let payout = universe.payout;

    if (isNaN(payout) || payout === null) {
        payout = 0;
    }

    const newPayout = new Big(payout).plus(new Big(amount));
    await universe.update({ payout: newPayout.toFixed(2) }, { transaction });

    return newPayout;
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to get payout:', error);
    throw error;
}
}
```

Comment: Re, "I acquire the locks in the same order on every thread (there are running the same code)" Running the same code does not always protect threads from deadlock. It's especially true in object-oriented programs where the locks may be embedded in objects that are passed to the function as arguments. The classic example is a function that takes two objects of the same type as arguments and acquires locks in both. All you have to do is have one thread call f(a,b) while another thread calls f(b,a), and a naive implementation of f will acquire the locks in opposite order in the two threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly why this worked, but here was my solution

As I guessed the issue was with

```
await updatePotSize(stockOwnerData.universeId, transaction)
await updatePayout(stockOwnerData.universeId, 1, transaction);
```

So I merged them into 1 and had them execute after the original transaction executed

```
await transaction.afterCommit(async (t) => {
        await sequelize.transaction({ isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE }, async (innerTransaction) => {
            await updatePotSizeAndPayout(stockOwnerData.universeId, 1, innerTransaction);
        });
    });
```

Additionally I needed to add

```
lock: transaction.LOCK.UPDATE
```

to the query

I dont love this solution, as now its possible for users to open a pack but not have the potSize or size of universe increase, but I guess I have to live with that